# Onclick, scroll to div that is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, wagtail

I'm working with the Wagtail CMS, most of my content is dynamically generated - which makes things like this a little tricky for me.

Basically I want to click on my sidebar item and scroll to that section within my page.

```
<div class="sidebar">
<nav>
  <ul>
    {% for block in page.article_content %}
    <li><a class="section-link" id="{{ block.value.header }}"
      href="">{{ block.value.header }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My sidebar code generates li elements for each block.value.header I have on the page.

```
<div class="container">
    {% for block in page.article_content %}
    <main>
      <section id="{{ block.value.header }}">
        <h1 class="headline-text section-header" >{{ block.value.header}}</h1>
        <div class="header-bar"></div>
        <div class="case-study-body-container" >
          {{ block.value.description|richtext }}
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    {% endfor %}
```

script.js looks like this

```
JS Code
    let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a.section-link");
    let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll("main section");

    console.log(mainNavLinks)

    let lastId;
    let cur = [];

    window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
      let fromTop = window.scrollY;

      mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
        let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

        if (
          section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
          section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
        ) {
          link.classList.add("current");
        } else {
          link.classList.remove("current");
        }
      });
    });
```

The error I'm getting at the moment is: **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.**

Heres what the page looks like to give you guys an idea [image]

Comment: Is there something wrong with something like `href="str.concat(' #', {{ block.value.header }});">` in your side links? Obviously you can expand this functionality out into JS to return the appropriate `#myelementID` if you wish to have the functionality out of `inline elements`

Comment: First thing is to determine whether this is an issue with the Javascript itself, or a "Wagtail is not outputting the HTML that the Javascript wants" issue. If you're not sure, try recreating the page as pure HTML outside of Wagtail and see whether the problem still exists there. That way, you'll have a more focused question that doesn't require people to be both Wagtail *and* Javascript experts.

Comment: @gasman recreating this with hard coded html is not challenging at all, in fact, I have done it before while learning HTML. Essentially, what it really boils down to is targeting specific elements with javascript that is generated through wagtail, which i'm not overly familiar with

Comment: OK, so you have a clear idea of what HTML you want Wagtail to output? If so, you'll get a better response if you ask the question "how do I get Wagtail to output X" - no need to bring up Javascript at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to wrap your js code like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    your js code
}
```